# Microsoft Excel - SumIF with WeekNum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the values with-in a data range, subtract value within a specific day.
I'm able to do first part - SUM  but got a problem when I tried to subtract.

[image]

Formula used on "Exclude Sunday" table

```
F3  =SUMIFS(B3:B17,A3:A17,">="&D3,A3:A17,"<="&E3)
```

Help on this above formula to subtract Sundays hours.

On Sunday Only table, help to add hours of Sundays only of each months.

I tried **SUMIFS** with **WEEKNUM**, but couldn't get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Weeknum() returns the number of the week, which is not useful in your scenario, since you want to evaluate the week day. That is what the Weekday() function does quite nicely. With the defaults, Weekday() returns 1 for a Sunday, 2 for Monday, and so on.

You can use Sumproduct to calculate a sum of all hours between two dates where the weekday is not Sunday like this in cell F3 of your screenshot.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY($A$3:$A$17)<>1)*($A$3:$A$17>=$D3)*($A$3:$A$17<=$E3)*B3:B17)
```

Copy down.

In order to sum all Sunday hours in January, you can use Sumproduct and compare the date formatted as "mmm" with the text in cell D10, and also use a condition to calculate only dates where the weekday is Sunday (i.e. 1). Cell E10 has the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$17*(TEXT($A$3:$A$17,"mmm")=$D10)*(WEEKDAY($A$3:$A$17)=1))
```